# SharePoint online: what is column "label applied" and "label setting"?

Tags: document-library, office-365, view

I see in the view of document libraries those fields. I do not think I have noticed them before. What is the feature they are related to? is it activated by some setting at tenancy level or is it standard feature for O365?

Comment: I believe it is part of the new retention feature that was revealed at Ignite. The retention will be applied via labels that will be associated with a defined policy.

Comment: Has anyone found additional information what the integers for 'Label applied by' and Label setting' columns indicate within the doc library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Labels can be connected with retention policies, e.g. to keep item for specific amount of years, or preserve it as a record https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Overview-of-labels-af398293-c69d-465e-a249-d74561552d30. If you look at the corresponding field names, they are about "Compliance Flags" which arguably is a better term.

However, currently both label setting and label applied by are presented as an integer (presumably, internal enum flag and the id of the user), which makes it quite cryptic.